# Appium server connecting to remote ADB

Tags: android, adb, appium

Is it possible to make an Appium server use a remote ADB server instead of the `localhost`?

It would be essential to be able to use Appium servers in a Dockerized environment.

Comment: As of Appium 1.7.0, there is now a capability for specifying the `remoteAdbHost`: https://github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating this issue and examining the answers, I think the short answer is: it is not possible currently without using a third party tool.

However, one workaround is possible in case of using Docker on a Linux system (similar can be achieved on Windows if the ADB server runs on the VM created by Docker Machine).

The ADB server runs on the Linux and the Appium servers running in the Docker containers can connect ADB on `localhost`. One need to use the `--privileged` and `-v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb/` so that the Docker containers can connect the devices.

That will work only, if the devices are connected to the same machine where the Docker containers run.

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished with the ADB connect function. From the Appium container, run `adb connect <host>:<port>` where `<host>:<port>` is the IP address/port of the remote ADB server (port 5555 is default).

For example, if the hardware device is physically connected at IP address 192.168.1.101, the adb command to connect would be
`adb connect 192.168.1.101:5555`

At this point, the remote device should be listed as connected if you run `adb devices` from the Appium host, and you can proceed with testing. To disconnect the remote device, use the adb disconnect function; e.g. `adb disconnect 192.168.1.101:5555`

If your goal is just to use USB connected hardware devices in a Dockerized Appium environment, another option is to use docker volumes to expose the host hardware to the container. Passing the `-v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb/` option to your docker run command will give the container full access to the USB bus and all connected devices.

Comment: No, you're confusing things. OP is not asking how to connect to the device from Appium, but how to connect to a remote ADB server from Appium. Appium => ADB server => device. Using `adb connect` just won't work if the ADB server is not on `localhost`. Typically when using ADB alone (not Appium), one would use `adb -H <host> -P <port> <command>` for talking to a remote ADB server. It seems Appium exposes [`remoteAdbHost`](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/acbc298202bcfbd5383964225899b293ef834a9c/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md) for doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to make appium server use a remote adb server.

You could look for open source libs such as [OPEN-STF](http://openstf.io/) which provide you a medium to access devices via adb remotely.

On your Appium interface all you need to do is execute setup/tests onto the same URL as the remote server url where the `appium-server-node` would be running.

Comment: What do you mean "execute tests onto the same URL"? Now each Appium node connects to Selenium Hub with a device specific configuration, and in the tests the Hub is targeted.

Comment: Hub is what I meant.

Comment: Does that mean that I can't target a remote ADB server in Appium without using another third party tool?